# SocketIO Chat - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've set up a socketio chat. I'm trying to display old messages (from mongodb) when a user joins the channel.

I'm able to join the chat for the first time, but if I load the page in a new tab I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nick' of undefined - in the console.

when I console.log(data.nick + data.msg), I get the data I'm looking for. I can't figure out what's causing this..

Please help!

Here's the relevant **client side code:**

```
socket.on('load old messages', function(data) {
        for(var i=0; data.length; i++) {
             displayMsg(data[i]);
        }

      });

      function displayMsg(data) {
          $chat.append('<span class="chatnick"><b>' + data.nick + ': </b></span><span class="chatmsg">' + data.msg + "</span><br/><hr>");
      }
```

Here's the relevant **server side code:**

```
var query = Chat.find({});
query.sort('-created').limit(8).exec(function(err, data) {
if(err) throw err;
socket.emit('load old messages', data);
});
```

Here is my **MongoDB code:**

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chat-logs', function(err) {
if(err) {
console.log(err);
} else {
console.log("Connected to mongodb!");
}
});
var chatSchema = mongoose.Schema({
nick: String,
msg: String,
// channel: String,
created: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
var Chat = mongoose.model('Message', chatSchema);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your for loop was wrong:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
```

I assume that was just a typo.

Comment: Coding can be so ridiculous sometimes.. Spend hours looking at it, only to miss something so small.. Thank you!